# Using .htaccess file for the mobile version of a site

Tags: .htaccess, jquery-mobile, user-agent

I have done a jQuery mobile site. I want to upload the this directory in the original site's FTP. now i want to detect the mobile site in the mobile device only. Thats why one can only open the mobile version in mobile device only.
 like i have my site url www.example.com which should be open in desktop site.
 and another site means mobile site should be open in www.example/mobile site.

i have found documention of detecting mobile version like this

```
# don't apply the rules if you're already in the mobile directory, infintine loop
# you'll want to test against the host if you're using a subdomain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
```

and i change the "mobiledirectoryhere" to my mobile version site directory "mobile". after that i upload the the file to the FTP and rename it as .htaccess

I went through the reference site `http://ohryan.ca/blog/2010/04/10/how-to-detect-mobile-visitors-using-htaccess-rewrite-rules-simplified/`

Comment: Sorry, i used that code, but it did not work.

Comment: does it do anything - what didn't work on it? Did you get a status code?

Comment: in the instruction there is written that, the mobile directory should be written in the place of "mobiledirectoryhere" which i did, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got easy solution for my site detection. Simply add the `.htaccess` file to the root directory with the following content.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.myurlname\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://m.myurlname.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

and then save it.